# clearing out a text input based on what is in the text field

Tags: swift, switch-statement, uitextfield

I have a text field (amount.text) that users are able to input numbers into. Once the user tapped off of the textfield I would run this function to see if the user doesn't have any text or just the $ symbol I add in some placeholder text.

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    switch(textField.tag){
    case 1:
        if(name.text == "")
        {
            name.text = "Statement Name"
        }
        break
    case 2:
        if(amount.text == "" || amount.text == "$")
        {
            amount.text = amountPlaceHolder
        }
        else
        {
         code....
        }
}
```

This was easy when the only currency symbol in the app was the $ symbol. With the update, I'm working on I allowing the users to pick their own currencies. I'm not sure how I can check to see if there are any numbers in the input area and if there isn't display the placeholder text. I was trying to use the currency symbol to check against but some of them are just letters.

For example. Let's say the user picks Chinese Yuan and the symbol that I get back for that is CY¥. So if they input 100 and that gets converted to CY¥100, and then they delete the 100 and the ¥, how could I check to see if the numbers are still there. My initial thought was to check against the currency symbol, but if they can delete part of the symbol, in this case, the ¥ then how can I check against that.

```
if(amount.text == "" || amount.text == currancy symbol)
        {
            amount.text = amountPlaceHolder
        }
```

Where the actual symbol is CY¥ but in theory, I would be checking just CY.

```
CY¥ == CY -> will not use place holder text.
```

I was hoping someone might have an idea or direction to point me in.

Comment: What are the currency symbols recognized by your app, other than `$`?

Comment: There are 160 of them.

Comment: I'm using the ones that come back from this: Locale.commonISOCurrencyCodes

Comment: That's smart! that array doesn't include "$", "€", "¥" though...

Comment: Thanks, but the issue is to check to see if its just a currency code or part of a code left and no numbers.

Comment: What do you mean bu “*part of a code*”? Could you please include examples in your question

Comment: @Carpsen90, just updated the question.

Comment: Is C accepted for CU¥? Should the same be applied for other currencies? For example should ‘EUR’, ‘EU’ and ‘E’ all be accepted?

Comment: Not sure I follow

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
if(amount.text == "" || amount.text == "$")
```

To this:

```
if ["", "$", "€", "¥"].contains(amount.text!)
```

You could define an array of recognized currencies :

```
let currencyStrings = ["$", "€", "¥"]
```

and use it like so:

```
if currencyStrings.contains(amount.text!) || amount.text!.isEmpty
```

As to the placeholder, take advantage of the `placeholder` property when you create your text field (and not in `textFieldDidEndEditing`):

```
amount.placeholder = amountPlaceHolder
```

*(Same goes for the `name` text field)*

---

### Bonus 1

To get all the currency codes and symbols, you could use this snippet:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
let currencies: Set<String> = Set(Locale.availableIdentifiers
    .map { Locale(identifier: $0) }
    .reduce(Set<String>(), { set, locale in
        var tempo = set
        formatter.locale = locale
        if let code = formatter.currencyCode {
            tempo.insert(code)
        }
        if let symbol = formatter.currencySymbol {
            tempo.insert(symbol)
        }
        return tempo
}))
```

Take into consideration that this set contains this symbol [`¤`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_sign_(typography)), which stands for an *unspecified currency*. I couldn't get the currency symbol for these two locales: `kea_CV` and `pt_CV`.

---

### Bonus 2

Here is another array of codes and symbols for common/active [cryptocurrencies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cryptocurrencies):

```
let crypto = ["BTC", "XBT", "₿", "LTC", "Ł", "NMC", "STC", "BCN", "PPC", "DOGE", "XDG", "Ð", "FTC", "₣", "GRC", "XPM", "XRP", "NXT", "AUR", "KOI", "COYE", "DASH", "NEO", "MZC", "XMR", "XEM", "POT", "AMP", "TIT", "XVG", "XLM", "VTC", "ETH", "ETC", "USDT", "NEU", "DCR", "LSK", "WAVES", "ZEC", "BCC", "BCH", "EOS", "ADA"]
```

Comment: I think your Bonus 1 returns over 700 currencies. And you're correct to allot of them I don't think have symbols.  Does Bonus 2 have all symbols except for 2 of them? Can you format a Locale based off of that list?